# Graphic presentation/analysis of multiple events of different character

Tags: data-visualization, recurrent-events

Edited;

Ive troede to specify my problem. Hope it makes more sense.

Im a surgeon doing research. I use SPSS for statistics but in the group we are also able to use 'R'.

We are performing af study investigating the development of complications after surgery and their relation to frailty. We are interested in number of complications, seriousness of complications and their development over time (after surgery).

We have 500 patients, that have gone through surgery. They are categorized within 3 groups of frailty (not frail, frail, very frail). Groups are not equally sized but roughly with 300ptt, 150ptt and 50 ptts in each respectively.

We have registered all complications after surgery and know what day these happened. NOTE that each patient often suffers from more than 1 complication.

Furthermore the complications are graded from 1-5 regarding seriousness (where 5 is death).

I would love to be able to illustrate data regarding:

- development over time
- cumulativeness in each group (but with regards to the diffent sizes of the groups - like a ratio)
- dropout when patient is death (like in a Kaplan-Meier curve)

Ive been trying to modify kaplan-Meier curves to be able to withtake multiple events, without luck.

Im looking for a kind of plot that are able to illustrate the cumulation of complications(y-axis) over time (x-axis) within the 3 groups separately. Any complication should be registered as a "jump" in the graph (as a KM-plot) and the height of the jump should illustrate the relativeness to the number of patients left in the group that can suffer a complication, meaning that dead patients should be censored (also as in a KM-plot). It would be lovely if censored data (death) were illustrated (again - like a KM-plot).
All in all a KM-like plot with rising graphs for 3 groups and with each individual being able to experience more than one event. If it is possible with a KM-algorithm in SPSS (or another software) we havent been able to figure it out.

Any good ideás as to where i should go. Maybe just a couple of keywords making it possible to improve my search-strategy on the internet.

Kindly.

Thomas K, Copenhagen.

Comment: There are several different quantities here - could you give a single specific example of what you would like to plot?  And if you want to have multiple events in a single plot, what are these events and what links them? Are they additive?

Comment: The events are complications. Patients in the most fragile group suffers from more complications. I would like to illustrate the relative (to the size of the group) number of complications within each of the groups over time (from date of operation) and preferably be able to discriminate when patients die.

Comment: That helps, though more detail might be useful. Please edit your question with the new information; the question is now closed because it needs more focus, and editing it to clarify your main question (with one such example) will get it evaluated for re-opening.